# Using Heroku Scheduler with Node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, scheduler

There is literally no tutorial about using Heroku Scheduler with Node.js. Assume that I have a function called **sayHello()** and I would like to run it every 10 mins. How can I use it in controller. In ruby you write **rake function_name()** however no explanation made for Node. Can I write **'/sayHello'** or I should do extra configuration?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Create the file `<project_root>/bin/say_hello`:

```
#! /app/.heroku/node/bin/node
function sayHello() {
    console.log('Hello');
}
sayHello();
process.exit();
```

Deploy to Heroku and test it with `$ heroku run say_hello` then add it to the scheduler with task name `say_hello`.

### Explanation

Take `say_hello.js` as an example of a Node.js script that you would normally run using `$ node say_hello.js`.

Turn it into a script by

1. removing the `.js` ending
2. inserting the 'shebang' at the top: `#! /app/bin/node` [1][2]
3. moving it into the `bin` directory [3]

[1] Read about the [shebang on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).
[2] The `node` executable is installed in `app/bin/node` on Heroku. You can check it out by logging into bash on Heroku with `$ heroku run bash` then asking `$ which node`.
[3] Heroku requires scripts to be placed in the `bin` directory. See [Defining Tasks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#defining-tasks) in the Heroku Dev Center.

I agree that the Heroku documentation for scheduling tasks is not very clear for anything other than Ruby scripts. I managed to work it out after some trial and error.

Comment: Great answer! What is the exit() method (I tried this example and received a method not defined error)?

Comment: To clarify, must the script be in the bin directory in the root of the project repo, or the bin of the dyno its self? I can see /bin/ when I do heroku run bash, but I can't deploy code there from git... Thanks!

Comment: @dancrews http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2014/02/04/maintainable-node-js-javascript-avoid-process-exit/

Comment: I found that using a bash script with the shebang did not allow me to use `var script = require('../path/to/script');`.  I switched to [Christophe's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16378771/517712) and it was a better solution for me.

Comment: asking `$ which node` in heroku bash gave me `/app/.heroku/node/bin/node` as a path for node in my case. Which I entered instead of app/bin/node, and it works perfectly. Thanks for the detailed walkthrough and note [2] in particular.

Comment: I used `#!/usr/bin/env node` instead of `#! /app/bin/node`.

Comment: very good explained. I used different default shebang /app/.heroku/node/bin/node

Comment: `process.exit();` immediatley after `sayHello` for example resulted in my script not finishing and only once removed did it run fully and complete? Thanks.

Answer (score 44):

A better approach is to define your schedule file called for example `worker.js` with following content:

```
function sayHello() {
    console.log('Hello');
}
sayHello();
```

and then in the heroku schedule, you just write `node worker` like you define it in the `Procfile` and that's all!

Comment: Thanks! This worked great for me and seems like a simpler approach.

Comment: what does heroku schedule refer to? is this a file i have to create myself? Please clarify

Comment: I needed to add `#!/usr/bin/env node` at the top of the file.

Comment: Any idea how to use node_modules though?

Answer (score 28):

Christophe's answer worked for me until I needed to pass a parameter to the script, at which point it failed.  The issue is that `node` should not be specified in the task. Here is how exactly to get it working:

1. In your Procfile, define a process type for your script. See below for a typical Procfile with a web process and, for running "scheduled_job.js", a second process type imaginatively named "worker".

   > ```
   > web: node app.js
   > worker: node scheduled_job.js
   > ```
2. In the Heroku scheduler's Task column, just enter the name of the process type ("worker" in this example) with or without parameters. **Don't enter 'node' before it**. Heroku shows a dollar sign in front of it, so examples of a valid setup would be `$ worker` (run without arguments) or `$ worker 123 abc` (to execute scheduled_job.js with arguments "123" and "abc")

Answer (score 7):

I am confused that nobody tried:

```
$ heroku run node yourScript.js
```

So put this in Heroku Scheduler

```
node yourScript.js
```

Worked for me.

PS: be sure to `import` everything your script needs.

Answer (score 5):

Following steps work in my situation.

1. In the root folder add `worker.js` file.
2. In worker.js. Write an simple function, like above.

   `function sayHello() {
     console.log('Hello');
   }
   sayHello();`
3. Go to heroku Scheduler add-ons. Click 'add new job' and type 'worker' in the field. Then set time interval and click save.

Here are something should notice

1. After update works setting.If using above example, you can use `heroku run node worker.js` to check if it work. It should be show 'Hello' in your terminal.
2. I use [express-babel](https://github.com/vmasto/express-babel) starter for my node.js project.

Answer (score 1):

Thnks so much for the previous answers here.

**I found the following worked for me where `feed.js` is the script to run as a job on Heroku.:**

`<PROJECT_ROOT>/bin/feed.js`

**The contents of `feed.js` start with:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

async function mediumFeed() {

  await fetch('https://medium.com/feed/stokedinfluence')
```

**And end with:**

```
}

mediumFeed();
```

**And on Heroku the job is defined as `node bin/medium_feed.js`:**

[image]

[image]

*To run the node js script locally `feed.js` you can use from the root of your project directory `node bin/feed.js` and to run via heroku you can use `heroku run feed.js --app <APP_NAME_NOT_PIPELINE_NAME>.` When using heroku command, this will run the job from the server where as running `node bin/feed.js` will run locally. Run locally to test and verify the code works, once deployed verify it works with the `heroku run...` command*