# Heroku scheduler with Node Js

Tags: node.js, heroku, scheduled-tasks

I've followed this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345664/using-heroku-scheduler-with-node-js) and it works but when I try to call my app nothing happens. I have my main function in app.js called

```
function start() { ... }
```

This is my task stored in bin which I know it works when I call:

```
#! /app/.heroku/node/bin/node
function mytask() {
  start();
}
initScrape();
process.exit();
```

After: `heroku run init mytask`

```
λ heroku run init_scrape                                 
Running mytask on dyno1... up, run.5157   
/app/bin/mytask:3                                   
  start();                                               
  ^                                                      

ReferenceError: start is not defined                     
    at mytask (/app/bin/mytask:3:3)             
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/bin/mytask:5:1)     
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)                
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)  
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)                    
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)          
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)        
    at startup (node.js:148:18)                          
    at node.js:405:3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to export start from where it is defined and your script needs to require the file that has `start()` defined. Otherwise how would it know where to find it?

So you probably need to modify your app.js and say `module.exports = start`. Then in the `mytask` file you do this:

```
#! /app/.heroku/node/bin/node
var start = require('./app.js');
function mytask() {
  start();
}
initScrape();
process.exit();
```