# Scheduled worker on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, scheduled-tasks

I'm working on this component that runs scheduled on Heroku and I can't make it run properly. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345664/using-heroku-scheduler-with-node-js?lq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951785/heroku-scheduler-with-node-js) posts to get it working. I manage to run the scheduled task on heroku according to `heroku logs`. The problem that I have is that if I run the code within a module (I need this to run on scheduled basis) it doesn't run the **xray** module and I'm not sure why this happens.

This is my code without module and its output if I run the code from the bin folder according to one of the links attached up here, which is what heroku will do to run the scheduled task:

```
var Xray = require('x-ray');

// helpers
var x = Xray({
  filters: {
    cleanPrice: function (value) {
      return typeof value === 'string' ? value.replace(/\r|\t|\n|€/g, "").trim() : value
    },
    whiteSpaces: function (value) {
      return typeof value === 'string' ? value.replace(/ +/g, ' ').trim() : value
    }
  }
});

console.log("START - Scraping categories...");

x('http://google.com', 'title')(function (err, title) {
  console.log(title) // Google
})
```

> λ bin\node init 
>   START - Scraping categories... 
>   Google

This is my code within a module and the output

```
module.exports = {
  start: function () {

    var Xray = require('x-ray');

    // helpers
    var x = Xray({
      filters: {
        cleanPrice: function (value) {
          return typeof value === 'string' ? value.replace(/\r|\t|\n|€/g, "").trim() : value
        },
        whiteSpaces: function (value) {
          return typeof value === 'string' ? value.replace(/ +/g, ' ').trim() : value
        }
      }
    });

    console.log("START - Scraping categories...");

    x('http://google.com', 'title')(function (err, title) {
      console.log(title) // Google
    })

  }
}
```

the output

> λ bin\node init 
>   START - Scraping categories...

I'm missing the word "Google". Why this happens if I put my code within a module???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the actual task

```
#! /app/.heroku/node/bin/node

"use strict";

var app = require('../src/app.js');
function initScrape() {
  app.start();
}
initScrape();
process.exit(1); // tell node to exit (prevent promise)
```

By adding `process.exit(1);` I was preventing any promise to be resolved. This is needed for nodejs to stop the execution.